# Visual Studio 2022 mstest .NETcore - Gives no explanation why it won't run unit tests or how to fix the problem

Tags: c#, .net-core, mstest, visual-studio-2022, testcontext

PRoj file

```
Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" 
"DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects.Core" V="4.3.0" "itext7" V="7.2.5" "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" V="7.0.0" "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" V="7.0.0" "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" V="17.5.0" "coverlet.collector" V="3.1.2" "MSTest.TestAdapter" V="3.0.2" "MSTest.TestFramework" V="3.0.2" "Selenium.Support" V="4.9.0" "Selenium.WebDriver" V="4.9.0" "Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" V="112.0.5615.4900" "SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" V="1.0.2"
```

```cs
public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)
{
   var _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
       .AddJsonFile(@"TestData.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
       .Build();

   if (_configuration != null)
   {
      pageLoadTimeout =    Convert.ToInt16(_configuration["TestDataCollection:PageLoadTimeout"]);
      ePortalUsername = _configuration["TestDataCollection: ePortalUsername"];
      ePortalPassword = _configuration["TestDataCollection: ePortalPassword"];
    }

    if (TestContext != null)
    {
       browser = browser = Convert.ToString(TestContext.Properties["Browser"]);
       url = Convert.ToString(TestContext.Properties["OLSPortalUrl"]);
    }
}
```

Here's json file

```json
{
  "__comments": "Test data is collection of TestDataInstance. Each instance contains testing   accounts and data",
  "TestDataCollection": [
   {
      "ePortalUserName": "some username",
      "ePortalPassword": "some password",
      "OLSPortalUrl": "http://www-test.someurl.com/",
      "PageLoadTimeout": "40"
   }
  ]
}
```

Here's my runsettings file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
     <TestRunParameters>
        <Parameter name="Browser" value="Chrome" />
        <Parameter name="Environment" value="TEST" />
        <Parameter name="OLSPortalUrl" value="http://www-test.paccarfinancial.com/" />
     </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>
```

Test output:

> ```
> Building Test Projects
> ========== Starting test run ==========
> ========== Test run finished: 0 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in < 1 ms ==========
> ```

Here is my Testclass and TestMethod

```cs
[TestClass]
public class Tests : BaseTestClass
{
    [TestCategory("Test"), TestMethod]
    public void PAC041_01_Navigate()
    {            
        if (browser != null && url != null)
        {
            driver = Utility.InitBrowser(browser, pageLoadTimeout);
            Utility.NavigateToUrl(url);
            Assert.AreEqual("Home Page", driver.Title);
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried removing json file and keeping only runsettings file still my tests are not picked up. Since i am on .NET core AppSettings is not supports so I have to use json for the testdata. I am not sure what wrong i am doing here. Can some one please help me with this?

Comment: In VS, open the **Output** window for Test discovery (not "Build") and show us what it says.

Comment: @Dai , Building Test Projects ========== Starting test run ========== ========== Test run finished: 0 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in < 1 ms ========== This is what it says. I don't have Test discovery but this is the output for Tests –

Comment: Show us your `csproj` file. I think you might have incorrect or insufficient NuGet `<PackageReference>` entries.

Comment: _"here it is"_ - where? you haven't edited your question to add it

Comment: since comment window accept less chars, I pasted the files and versions from proj file. I was pulled into a meeting before . So i was not able to edit it.

Comment: Don't use comments for posting code: edit your original post instead.

Comment: Don't you also need a `[ClassInitialize]` over your ClassInit method? (but still, the `[TestClass]` should already be found)

Comment: Yes, they are there. forgot to paste it here

Comment: I figured out why it was not working. In ClassInit, i was not using the TestContext variable declared in the method, was rather using TextContext variable defined globally. Removed the Textcontext defined globally and using the variable declared in the ClassInit method. Thanks Dar for atleast looking into it.